# how to add image to JButton

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton

Okay so i have been reading up on how to add Images onto a JButton by using ImageIcon but it still seems to not work for me, below is my code, i am using Eclipse workspace and would like some help the below code block is the program without the imports

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

//Declaration of JPanels
JPanel Left = new JPanel(null);
JPanel Right = new JPanel(null);
JPanel TopAd = new JPanel(null);
JPanel RightAd = new JPanel(null);
//Decleration For Right JPanel
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("buttonicon.bmp");
JButton[] Case = new JButton[26];
public Gui() {
    File imageCheck = new File("src/buttonicon.bmp");
    if (imageCheck.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Image file found!");
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            Case[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf((i + 1)));
            Case[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/buttonicon.bmp"));
        }
    }
    setLayout(null);
    add(Left);
    add(Right);
    add(TopAd);
    add(RightAd);
    Left.setBounds(10, 20, 220, 685);
    Left.setBackground(Color.black);
    Right.setBounds(240, 125, 500, 580);
    Right.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    TopAd.setBounds(240, 20, 635, 95);
    TopAd.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    RightAd.setBounds(750, 125, 125, 580);
    RightAd.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    //Initalising Right JPanel
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        Right.add(Case[i]);
    }
    Case[0].setBounds(20, 5, 110, 75);
    Case[1].setBounds(135, 5, 110, 75);
    Case[2].setBounds(250, 5, 110, 75);
    Case[3].setBounds(365, 5, 110, 75);
    Case[4].setBounds(20, 85, 110, 75);
    Case[5].setBounds(135, 85, 110, 75);
    Case[6].setBounds(250, 85, 110, 75);
    Case[7].setBounds(365, 85, 110, 75);
    Case[8].setBounds(20, 165, 110, 75);
    Case[9].setBounds(135, 165, 110, 75);
    Case[10].setBounds(250, 165, 110, 75);
    Case[11].setBounds(365, 165, 110, 75);
    Case[12].setBounds(20, 245, 110, 75);
    Case[13].setBounds(135, 245, 110, 75);
    Case[14].setBounds(250, 245, 110, 75);
    Case[15].setBounds(365, 245, 110, 75);
    Case[16].setBounds(20, 325, 110, 75);
    Case[17].setBounds(135, 325, 110, 75);
    Case[18].setBounds(250, 325, 110, 75);
    Case[19].setBounds(365, 325, 110, 75);
    Case[20].setBounds(20, 405, 110, 75);
    Case[21].setBounds(135, 405, 110, 75);
    Case[22].setBounds(250, 405, 110, 75);
    Case[23].setBounds(365, 405, 110, 75);
    Case[24].setBounds(135, 485, 110, 75);
    Case[25].setBounds(250, 485, 110, 75);

}
```

}

The Problem i am getting is

```
    File imageCheck = new File("src/buttonicon.bmp");
    if (imageCheck.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Image file found!");
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            Case[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf((i + 1)));
            Case[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/buttonicon.bmp"));
        }
    }
```

i have put an if statement in to check if the file exists and it does. there is no error thrown but the buttons are still staying as the default blue color, the button has the same resolution as the image aswell if thats any help.

also if anyone could help me out with an easier way of setting the code out and replacing tabs with spaces it would be highly greatful (i like using tabs instead of spaces)

Comment: Are you aware that you are using three different paths to get the icon in different places of your code?

Comment: yeah i am but the image still doesnt load i converted the image to a few types just to check i have tried png bmp and gif so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageIcon` tries to load the image in the background which is why you don't get an error when something is wrong. It just silently fails and expects you to call `getImageLoadStatus()` to see whether the image could be loaded.

I'm not sure BMP is supported by Java. Try PNG images instead.

Comment: thanks for the help :D png worked but the load image status didnt work?

Comment: When you talk to someone, please never say "didn't work." Always say **exactly** what you did, what you **expected** to happen and what happened **instead**.

Answer (score 0):

Add your images in your source and then you can try loading the images as,

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("src/buttonicon.bmp"));
Case[i].setIcon = new JButton (img);
```

or

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("src/buttonicon.bmp"));
Case[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```